# Assigning arguments to local variables in closure

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

Here is a currying snippet from [javascript patterns](http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/):

```
function add(x, y) {
    var oldx = x, oldy = y;
    if (typeof oldy === "undefined") { // partial
        return function (newy) {
             return oldx + newy;
        }
    }
    // full application
    return x + y;
}
```

ref: https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/function-patterns/currying.html

What is the point of local vars oldx and oldy?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think there is no point in having "old" variables here. Using x and y would be equivalent. But someone with more knowledge will provide a better answer :)

Comment: it doesn't seem necessary, the function would be fine without oldx or oldy.

Comment: honestly - I don't see any point in copying them except for the naming to make a clear distinction between "old" and "new" within the anonymous function. Furthermore this piece of code could be cleaner by calling `add(oldx, newy)` in the inner function, so the actual work would only be coded once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `oldx` and `oldy` are completely unnecessary here; the code behaves identically without them:

```
function add(x, y) {
    if (typeof y === "undefined") { // partial
        return function (y) {
             return x + y;
        }
    }
    // full application
    return x + y;
}
```

The function being returned here has access to outer-scope variables regardless of whether those variables are declared with `var` or declared as formal arguments to an outer function.

Generally speaking, if `x` is a primitive, it might sometimes make sense to assign it to a new variable if you needed a *copy* of that value to alter independently of the original:

```
function foo(x) {
    var newX = x;
    newX += 7;
    // now newX and x are different
    // ...
}
```

**However**, that need does not exist in this code, so it's totally unnecessary.